# Using values from table in QGIS Modeler for filtering

Tags: csv, qgis-modeler, table, feature-filter

I have a list of values (species names) in a .csv file and a vector layer of sightings of many species.

Is there a way to load the list in the QGIS Modeler and use it to filter my vector layer so that the new layer only contains species from my list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the list as a delimited text layer then **Join attributes by field value** with "Discard records which could not be joined":

[image]